# react-static, spark java, jetty, proguard - all involved, who is to blame?

Tags: reactjs, proguard, spark-java

Well, this seems to be weird...

But to start from the beginning: I'm having a Java 8 console app, hosting a REST API via the great Java Spark package (http://sparkjava.com/). The internal web server exposes - besides the REST API - a static HTML "app", which is made using the react-static package (https://github.com/nozzle/react-static). This is accessible via `localhost:5000` and works fine. I can roll my JAR and launch the JAR via `java -jar MyJar.jar` and open `localhost:5000` in the browser: Both REST API and Web Interface are there. So far so good.

But if I obfuscate the JAR using proguard, out of the sudden the web server is giving me a 302 redirect on my request to `localhost:5000`. It requests `localhost:5000/index.html` then, which in turn causes a 404 in my Web App, because `index.html` (although there as static file) is not a valid route.

To summarize: Everything fine with development and productive, unobfuscated JAR. The webserver delivers the contents of the static index.html file with 200 OK. If the JAR is obfuscated, the server responds with 302 and redirects to index.html, which causes the ReactJS app to give 404.

Here both cases in a Chrome screenshot.

Good

[image]

Not good

[image]

I'm currently a bit off track and don't know, where to look at first with this issue. Does anybody have a pointer?

Comment: Do you have a Spark Java route for `/` (root)? If you don't, you could add it and then control yourself the behavior when requesting `localhost:5000`.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. This route is not hit, as long as `staticFileLocation("/public");` is set. If I remove that, I have full control. But I don't intend to rewrite Jetty functionality here. Please note: The 302 behaviour is shown by the obfuscated version only...

Comment: Don't think there is enough to go on, yet; could you create a minimal example showing an index page that you have tested with proguard to ensure the issue remains?

Comment: @Quaternion: Thanks for chiming in. I could work around by making react-static able to handle 404 by redirecting it to my home page. By that I can live with the redirection to index.html. It does not come up with 404 anymore. Issue closed